# Transformation of function $y = x^2 $

Tags: functions

I want to transform function $y = x^2$ to $y = 4 x^2 $. Now this transformed function can be thought of as $ y/4 = x^2$ or $ y = (2x)^2$. If it is $ y/4 = x^2$, then this is a vertical stretch by a factor of 4 and if it is $ y = (2x)^2 $, then this is a horizontal compression by a factor of 2. Now, point $(1,1)$ is on the original curve. If we think of vertical stretch, then $(1,1)$ is transformed into $(1,4)$ and if we think of horizontal compression, then $(1,1)$ is transformed into $(\frac{1}{2}, 1) $. So, where does point $(1,1)$ transform to ? It can not go into two different points depending upon how we think of the transformation of the function.

Comment: It goes to (1,4) in this case we can put the same x coordinate into both functions and see there corresponding y coordinate

Comment: @Henry, if you check the answer below, Ross is saying that we can have many different mappings for $(1,1)$ depending upon how we think of this transformation.

Comment: It depends on whether you want the same x or y coordinate or neither tbh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it can.  The transformations are different.  Both take $(1,1)$ to a point on the curve.  You can find some intermediate transformations, like $y/2=(\sqrt 2 x)^2$.  This will take $(1,1)$ to $(\sqrt 2, 2)$, which is again on the new curve.  There are many continuous transformations between the two curves.

Comment: This is strange. So, different transformations can have same equation it seems. If we consider going from $y = x^2$ to $y = (x-2)^2$, then $(1,1)$ gets mapped to $(3,1)$. There is no other way. So, in this case mapping is unique.

Comment: No, it is not strange.  You are mapping one line to another line in an order preserving way.  There are lots of ways to do that.  You should think about mapping the $x$ coordinates, then letting $y$ go where it has to go.  There is no requirement that the mapping be linear in either coordinate.